# How to get website information with unix

Tags: unix

Using unix commands, how would I be able to take website information and place it inside a variable?

I have been practicing with curl -sS which allows me to strip out the download progress output and just print the downloaded data (or any possible error) in the console. If there is another method, I would be glad to hear it.

But so far I have a website and I want to get certain information out of it, so I am using curl and cut like so:

```
curl -sS "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_judo?action=raw | cut -c"19-"
```

How would I put this into a variable? My attempts have not been successful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap any command in `$(`...`)` to capture the output in the shell, which you could then assign to a variable (or do anything else you want with it):

```
var=$(curl -sS "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_judo?action=raw | cut -c"19-")
```